# Как заменить элемент массива в руби?

Tags: массивы, ruby

Есть задача. 
"Дан целочисленный массив. Заменить все положительные элементы на значение минимального."
Нужно использовать итерератор each. Но если можно, покажите и пример с циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать.  На *StackOverflow* не очень принято задавать
вопросы без кода (прямо в вопросе, *не скриншот, чёрт побери*),
за крайне редкими исключениями.  Тем более, когда речь идёт об учебных
заданиях.

Вот вам три варианта:

```ruby
# Non-smoker's code with map!.
# Optimised for size.
init = [0, -1, 2, -2, 1]
min = init.min
init.map! { |e| e > 0 ? min : e }
puts init.to_s

# Non-smoker's code with map.
# Optimised for clarity and correctness.
init = [0, -1, 2, -2, 1]
min = init.min
a = init.map { |e| e > 0 ? min : e }
puts a.to_s

# Smoker's code: each.
init = [0, -1, 2, -2, 1]
min = init.min
a = []
init.each { |e| a << (e > 0 ? min : e) }
puts a.to_s
```